# Highlight duplicate values in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I need to highlight the duplicate values from a cell to a list in excel.

Here is the input cell(In One cell)

```
1A - London,Perth,Dublin
```

List to compare

```
2A  Paris
3A  London
4A  New York
5A  Dublin
6A  Perth
7A  Washington
8A  Mumbai
9A  Monacco
10A Dublin
11A Shanghai
12A London
```

I need to highlight the duplicate values. Eg. London, Perth and Dublin Should get Highlighted(Dublin & London appears twice so it should be highlighted twice)

Comment: What have you tried to do? Where is your VBA code and/or formulas encountering problems? You need to ask a more specific question if you hope to get an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try conditionally formatting `A2:A12` with the following formula:

`=IF(ISERROR(SEARCH("*"&$A2&"*", $A$1)>0), FALSE, TRUE)` (see screenshots below).

[image: Conditional formatting formula]

[image: Conditional formatting range]

Comment: No problem Kunal. If the answer is what you were looking for, please accept the answer by clicking the tick next to it. Thanks.