# Find duplicates from multiple sheets in a workbook

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have a 600 000 data in one sheet. In "column I", I have phone numbers in Sheet1, sheet2, sheet3 and sheet4. I want to compare duplicates across sheets and highlight duplicate values in it.

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: This may be silly but what does 6 lac mean?

Comment: Just a reference: [site one](https://excelchamps.com/blog/highlight-duplicate-values-vba/), [site two](http://www.thesmallman.com/find-duplicates-with-vba:)

Comment: @Marcucciboy2 It's Indian word for 100 000, usually spelled lakh.

Comment: If you have 600,000 rows per sheet, my solution is probably not the way to go. I will leave it in hopes someone can build on/improve. Mine took 2 min with 10,000 rows per sheet. Are you sure you want to highlight? Sorting this by color is going to be gruesomely slow since excel isn't the ideal application for data of this size. You may be better off with a `COUNTIF` equation or switching to access (if you are limited to MS)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Highlight duplicate values in excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30983847/highlight-duplicate-values-in-excel)

Comment: Use `Scripting.Dictionary` or `collection` then compare across sheets

Answer (score 1):

This will highlight duplicates across sheets. You can use simple `Conditional Formatting` to call out duplicates on the same sheet.

---

**Update:** If each sheet has 10,000 identical rows, the macro takes 2 minutes (or 156.4063 seconds to be precise) to run with `ScreenUpdating` toggled off. That means 30,000 cells were highlighted on this timing test.

---

```
Option Explicit

Sub Duplicate_Digits()

Dim ws1 As Worksheet: Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
Dim ws2 As Worksheet: Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")
Dim ws3 As Worksheet: Set ws3 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet3")
Dim Numbers1, Numbers2, Numbers3, i
Dim Found As Range

Numbers1 = ws1.Range("I2:I" & ws1.Range("I" & ws1.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Value
Numbers2 = ws2.Range("I2:I" & ws2.Range("I" & ws2.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Value
Numbers3 = ws3.Range("I2:I" & ws3.Range("I" & ws3.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Value

For i = LBound(Numbers2, 1) To UBound(Numbers2, 1)
    Set Found = ws1.Range("I:I").Find(Numbers2(i, 1))
        If Not Found Is Nothing Then
            Found.Interior.Color = vbYellow
        End If
    Set Found = Nothing
Next i

For i = LBound(Numbers3, 1) To UBound(Numbers3, 1)
    Set Found = ws1.Range("I:I").Find(Numbers3(i, 1))
        If Not Found Is Nothing Then
            Found.Interior.Color = vbYellow
        End If
    Set Found = Nothing
Next i

For i = LBound(Numbers1, 1) To UBound(Numbers1, 1)
    Set Found = ws2.Range("I:I").Find(Numbers1(i, 1))
        If Not Found Is Nothing Then
            Found.Interior.Color = vbYellow
        End If
    Set Found = Nothing
Next i

For i = LBound(Numbers3, 1) To UBound(Numbers3, 1)
    Set Found = ws2.Range("I:I").Find(Numbers3(i, 1))
        If Not Found Is Nothing Then
            Found.Interior.Color = vbYellow
        End If
    Set Found = Nothing
Next i

For i = LBound(Numbers1, 1) To UBound(Numbers1, 1)
    Set Found = ws3.Range("I:I").Find(Numbers1(i, 1))
        If Not Found Is Nothing Then
            Found.Interior.Color = vbYellow
        End If
    Set Found = Nothing
Next i

For i = LBound(Numbers2, 1) To UBound(Numbers2, 1)
    Set Found = ws3.Range("I:I").Find(Numbers2(i, 1))
        If Not Found Is Nothing Then
            Found.Interior.Color = vbYellow
        End If
    Set Found = Nothing
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am not good at VBA. I can only add and run VBA code. Will this code highlight the duplicate across sheets :)

Comment: Yes- it does but you may a longer run the time than you’d like

Comment: This seems like a pretty reasonable method given the task.

Answer (score 0):

*I'm not sure how resource intensive this will be, someone else please chime in if they think it won't work on OP's 600,000 rows.*

---

You could use `=COUNTIFS()` in a helper column to flag duplicate values.

Put this formula in `K1` and autofill to the bottom:

```
=COUNTIFS(A:A,A1)
```

If the formula shows `1` it is not a duplicate, if it shows any value `>1` then it is a duplicate.