# Hide or unhide sheet depending on cell value

Tags: excel, vba

I am looking to write a code about hiding or un-hiding worksheets in Excel depending the value of a cell.

I have reached to this

```
Sub Hide_Un()
    If Range("b4").Value = "yes" Then
        sheets(2).Visible = True
    ElseIf Range("b4").Value = "no" Then
        sheets(2).Visible = False
    End If

    If Range("b5").Value = "yes" Then
        sheets(3).Visible = True
    ElseIf Range("b5").Value = "no" Then
        sheets(3).Visible = False
    End If
```

There are about 100 sheets and I can't do this procedure every time I add a new sheet.

I need a code to hide or unhide each worksheet depending my declaration to a cell.

Example B1="yes" (visible) or B1="no" (not visible)

Comment: So you have one sheet that says which sheets should be hidden going down Column B?

Comment: Yes that is corect

Comment: What is the name of this sheet? Does it have a header? I ask because we need to know if Row 1 corresponds to `Sheet(1)` or `Sheet(2)`. What row is the first "yes" or "no" on? Is row 4 the first "yes" or "no"?

Comment: The first sheet is named "TOC". and i am running below the macro

Comment: Sub ListSheets()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim x As Integer
x = 3
sheets("TOC").Range("A:A").Clear
 For Each ws In Worksheets
     sheets("TOC").Cells(x, 1) = ws.Name
     x = x + 1
Next ws
 
End Sub

Comment: but despite my last commends. your conclusions are correct. No headers and the row 4 is referring to sheet2 because sheet1=TOC

Comment: What does row 2 refer to? There is no `Sheet(0)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `Option Compare Text` makes this non case sensitive. This way `YES` = `yes`. Without this Option, they would not be equal
2. You may need to account for the option of the value being neither `yes` or `no`. What if value is `y` or `n` or `yes` with a lagging space?
3. Using the sheet index number (`Sheet(n)`) can be problematic if users have the option to add/move/delete sheets in the book.
4. It looks like the row number relates to sheet number by `Sheet # = Row -2`. I am starting the loop at 4. The lowest this could be is 3 - other wise you will end up trying to hide a sheet that can**not** exist

---

```
Option Explicit
Option Compare Text

Sub Hide_Un()

Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("TOC")
Dim i

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For i = 4 To ws.Range("B" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        If ws.Range("B" & i) = "yes" Then
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets(i - 2).Visible = xlSheetVisible
        ElseIf ws.Range("B" & i) = "no" Then
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets(i - 2).Visible = xlSheetHidden
        Else 'What if the cell is neither?
            'Do what you want if the cell is not "yes" or "no"
        End If
    Next i
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: You should consider Jeepeds solution. If you change a status from "yes" to "no" or add a new row, you need to re-run this for every sheet. His solution only checks sheets that need to be checked so it is going to be more efficient.......... *way to go anticipating needs*

Answer (score 2):

Put this code into the ThisWorkbook code sheet.

```
Option Explicit    

Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)

    Select Case LCase(Sh.Name)
        Case "toc"
            If Not Intersect(Target, Sh.Range("B:B")) Is Nothing Then
                Dim t As Range
                For Each t In Intersect(Target, Sh.Range("B:B"))
                    If t.Row > 3 Then
                        Worksheets(t.Row - 2).Visible = _
                            CBool(LCase(t.Value) = "yes")
                    End If
                Next t
            End If
        Case Else
            'do nothing
    End Select

End Sub
```

Comment: JEEPED! I posted a solution earlier [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51810559/find-duplicates-from-multiple-sheets-in-a-workbook/51810999#51810999) that, well, honestly, sucks. Would like to see your solution - need to branch out of simple loops and am really curious how a 90K G would do it! Not a demand of course, just if you are up for it :)

Comment: My bad, 91.5K G*

Comment: I'll try to have a look a little later on.

Comment: @Jeeped; If `B4` value was "Yes", that means `Sheet2` was set to visible. If the user changes `B4` value from "Yes" to "No", won't the worksheet still be visible? or am I missing something?

Comment: If B4 is anything but Yes then `Worksheets(t.Row - 2).Visible` is false.