# How do I hide all tabs without anything in cell F6?

Tags: excel, vba, printing

I have a macro to merge multiple excel workbooks and then print everything instead of having to open each workbook individually.

However, in each of these workbooks are blank template tabs called PR1,2,3,4,5 etc.
Is there a way to loop through each tab in the merged workbook and hide all tabs that don't have anything in a specific cell (in this case F6)?

In a perfect world if an employee uses the template tabs, they are supposed to rename the tab itself. But they don't always do this so I don't want to hide based on tab name.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: There are many posts on how to iterate the sheets in a workbook.  What have you tried and where are you stuck.  Right now it seems as if you are trying to get us to write your code for you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hide or unhide sheet depending on cell value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51812648/hide-or-unhide-sheet-depending-on-cell-value)

Answer (score 0):

The below is NOT the correct code but the guidelines on how to proceed.

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    Dim ws As Worksheet

    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets

        With ws
            'If sheet name is Sheet1 then delete
            If .Name = "Sheet1" Then
                .Delete
            End If

        End With

    Next ws

 End Sub
```